# JSON Data is nil after decoding

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

Guys I am getting a response for an api call I make. it returns the whole response and I give it to the method like.

```
completionHandler(response: response, error: nil)
```

then by doing

```
print(response.description)
```

The result is that I get headers statuscode etc.

```
URL:
removed

Status Code:
200

Headers:
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Content-Length: 2423
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
SessionID: removed
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 12:50:14 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

Payload:
[{"id":148,"name":"Amsterdam","avatar":"removed","cover":"removed"}]
```

The part I am mostly interested in is this part

```
Payload:
[{"id":148,"name":"Amsterdam","avatar":"removed","cover":"removed"}]
```

Somehow I can't extract that array of json objects. Anyone who can help me out on how to get this?

EDIT: added the method where I receive the response and pass it through

```
func requestObj(url: Routes, params: Dictionary<String, String>?, completionHandler: (response: Response?, error: NSError?) -> ())
{
    self.requestConfig(completionHandler: { () -> () in
        if let req = NSMutableURLRequest(urlString: self.config!.api!.baseUrl! + "/v2" + url.rawValue) {
            do {
                req.addValue(String(self.config!.api!.token!), forHTTPHeaderField: "Token")
                req.addValue(String(self.sessionID), forHTTPHeaderField: "SessionID")
                let opt = HTTP(req)
                opt.start { response in
                    if let err = response.error {
                        print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        print("opt finished with error info: \(response.description)")
                        completionHandler(response: nil, error: nil)
                    }
                    completionHandler(response: response, error: nil)
                    //print("data is: \(response.data)") access the response of the data with response.data
                }
            }
        }
    }) // request a valid config before doing anything
}
```

This is called with

```
    adapter.requestObj(APIAdapter.Routes.getMunicipalities, params: nil, completionHandler: {(
        response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response.description)
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is the type of `response`? Does it not contain a property that represents the response body?

Comment: You should get the the JSON data in response data variable. Kindly paste more code so that question becomes clearer. In case of NSURLConnection  you get the response data in connection delegate method didReceiveData:.

Comment: @EricD. the response is of type Response. the property is ( i Assume ) "Payload:" right?

Comment: I don't know any `Response` type. Is it from a library? Is it a custom type from elsewhere in your code? Where does it come from?

Comment: ah yes sorry I am using https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP library to handle the http requests for me. @EricD. its basically a http response

Comment: @EricD. I added more code of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

For [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP), you can get the response body with:

```
response.data
```

Comment: tried this as well. When I give back that it returns NSData. then I want to put it as JSON to save it in a realm object ( see realm.io ) instead of JSONJoy object that is made for SwiftHTTP. That is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Your question was how to get the data from the response object. I believe I've answered to that. Now if you have a new request, like how to get the json objects from the data then use Realm to save it, that would be an entirely different question to post. :)

Comment: How come.. when I do  do {
                    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    print(jsonResult)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }

I get nil then? ( even without using realm or anything )

Comment: I told you to use `response.data` but you're still using `response`, that's your error.

Comment: No I changed my method to return response.data 
                        completionHandler(response: response.data, error: nil) which is NSData as return value for that method. so response on that part is the NSData

Answer (score 0):

Have you  already tried with "SwiftyJson" you could save the data in a JSON object and then access the data as a Dictionary here's how I deal with the data

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
 func RequestImages()
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.500px.com/v1/photos",parameters:["consumer_key":"gRU4LletUCA9RiOQhaJBAt62UyRRYUE6vsIcC7fO"])
        .responseJSON { _,_,result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                debugPrint(data)
                self.Photos = self.ParseJSON(json)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToCollection", sender: self)
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }       
    }
}
```

here is some code where I use a library called Alamofire where i retrieve a response in JSON, then if data has be found i save the data in a JSON object provided by the SwiftyJSON library

```
let json = JSON(data)
```

then I have a collection of an "Image" mode called "Photos" i fill this collection by parsing the JSON data as the following

```
 func ParseJSON(json:JSON)->[Image]
{
    //Get Image_URL
    var pictures = [Image]()
    for result in json["photos"].arrayValue
    {
        pictures.append(Image(url: result["image_url"].stringValue, name: result["name"].stringValue, news: result["description"].stringValue))
    }   
    debugPrint(pictures)
    return pictures

}
```

I hope my implementation helps you Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  get_data_from_url("http://yourURL")


 }


func get_data_from_url(url:String) {

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    Id = label1.text //your request parameters 
    JId = label2.text //your request parameters 

    var post:NSString = "uid=\(Id)&jid=\(JId)"
    //NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)


    if  urlData != nil && reponseError == nil {

        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        //NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {

            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData)

            if Id != nil {

            extract_json(urlData!)

            }



        } else {


            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()

        }


    } else {


        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
        if let error = reponseError {
            alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
        }
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()

    }

}

  func extract_json(data:NSData) { 

    var error: NSError?

    let jsonData:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSArray


    let Id_temp: AnyObject? = ((jsonData)[0] as! NSDictionary)["id"]
    let Name_temp: AnyObject? = ((jsonData)[0] as! NSDictionary)["name"]
}
```

First go to this site and validate your URL

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog ( GOOGLE extenstion )
then replace below given values according to your settings :-

```
  request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];
```

Then you can do `[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@""]` to retrieve values.

This is Objective C, but I am sure it must be similar in Swift.

Comment: I tried that by returning the response.data but that give me nil :/

Comment: @Reshad Did you check whether the `error` reference had a value?

Comment: @CraigOtis yes. I tried it with the new Do {} Catch {} block and it didn't enter the error. instead it printed the value from Do but it was nil

Comment: Can you print the headers you get, please?